# Non-scrollable ListView inside ScrollView with different size items

Tags: android, listview

Non-scrollable ListView inside ScrollView with different size items. actually i tried getting no of list items and giving height = no of items* height of first item, but the issue is i have items with different height in list so last item sometimes not visible.
here is my custom listview:

```
public class ExpandedListView  extends ListView {

    private android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
    private int old_count = 0;
    int limit=0;
    public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getCount() != old_count) {
            old_count = getCount();
            params = getLayoutParams();
            int height=0;

            int h =getCount() * (old_count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getHeight() : 0);

            int minHeight=setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(this);
            if (h>minHeight) {
                params.height=h+8 * (getCount() - 1)+25;
                setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

    public static int setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = listAdapter.getCount(); i < len; i++) { 
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0); 
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1))+100;

        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return params.height;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your effort. Post some code.

Comment: This code seems to be fine. Try setting `Margin bottom` to your list view and check

Comment: problem is if i have first item of 20 dp and other of 80 dp and 60 dp respectively list will take 60 dp heght(20*3) but it should take 20+80+60=160dp. How should i do???

Comment: `listItem.getMeasuredHeight();` will get the height of the single item whatever it is. It will add the height and update! Isn't it work by adding another 100 dp to the height?

Comment: we can get height of first item only as getChildAt(1).getHeight() or  at other position give null.  and if i use it in adapter it return 0.

Answer (score 0):

i not understand your question exact what you want.

If you want to make listview scrolable with same heights and width of every listview item then use inflater.make single row and use this in array using inflater.

if your question is this then i show you the code of listview with same heighta and width of every listview item.

Comment: i dont want to make listview scrollable as listview is placed in scrollview due to some requirements. I want listview to expand fully without any scroll. But i have different items with different heights.